# Sql query to take Value from short text datatype column and place it in a date datatype column

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sql query for converting short Text datatype date value in Format 22.02.2020 and update it in a date datatype column in Ms access

Comment: `CDate("22.02.2020")`

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply I have a column  start date which I having a date value 22.02.2020 in short text datatype and I have a new column of date datatype I want a query to update start date column values in new column having date datatype please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try settings-independent variant

```sql
UPDATE table
SET date_column = DateSerial( RIGHT(str_column, 4),
                              MID(str_column, 4, 2),
                              LEFT(str_column, 2) )
```

This code assumes that year is 4-digit always and month/day are zero-padded.

Answer (score 0):

VBA doesn't recognise *dot* as a date separator, so you must replace that in your query with the date separator:

```
Update
    YourTable
Set 
    [TrueDate] = DateValue(Replace([TextDate], ".", "/"))
```

Comment: *VBA doesn't recognise dot as a date separator* Depends on OS (national) settings for a date format.

Comment: Can you please type the query to use in Ms access to do the same please

Comment: Sure. See extended answer, please.